# Logging a key press in qualtrics using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keypress, qualtrics

I'm running an IAT in qualtrics and since they switched to their new engine, my JavaScript does not work. I don't know JavaScript well and cannot figure out, for the life of me, how to allow people to move to the next portion by pressing shift and z. Right now, I have this code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    this.disableNextButton();
    this.disablePreviousButton();
    this.hideNextButton();
    this.hidePreviousButton();
    this.hideChoices();

    var that = this;
    (function(){that.clickNextButton();}).delay(5);
});
```

The last two lines are what is not working. Right now, as its written, it delays and then auto advances after 5 seconds. What I want it to do, however, is allow people to move on (the clickNextButton function) when they press shift+z. Can anyone help me with this?

https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html

Answer (score 0):

update:

This seems to do the trick, but I need to log two keys at once, and don't know how. More importantly, it seems to auto log it when I press z once and automatically advance through multiple questions...

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    this.disableNextButton();
    this.disablePreviousButton();
    this.hideNextButton();
    this.hidePreviousButton();
    this.hideChoices();

    var that = this;
    Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 90) {
        that.clickNextButton();
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Since this answer doesn't completely solve your problem, you should have edited your original post instead of adding this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry! Never used stack overflow before, but thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can only advance through pages, not questions.  With this approach you need one question per page.

You can handle multiple keycodes with "or", "else if", or "switch".  Since there are only two, "or" is probably the easiest:

```
Event.observe(document, 'keydown', function keydownCallback(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 90 || e.keyCode == 89) {
    that.clickNextButton();
    }
});
```